# approval in a single step, returning the first answer

Tags: approval-process, approval-step

I have an approval process with 4 steps, with various designated approvers, one for each. I need that when one of them approves the opportunity, to end the process, making his answer the final result. Right now, this only happens is if an opportunity has criteria to reach only one of them. When this record finds its way to multiple steps and its respective approvals, so that's the current unwanted behavior.

Each of the 4 steps is configured like this: even if it can approved in various steps, it must be approved or not on the first one, and not even bother the next user. Shouldn't that "Approve or reject based on the FIRST response." option stop the process? And that "The approver's delegate may also approve this request." refers to a custom lookup field in the user, matching the intended approver.
[image]

and this is an example of that. You see the 2 steps? The last one should be the first and only approver.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really sure I understand your question.  "Shouldn't that "Approve or reject based on the FIRST response." option stop the process? "   No - it only applies to that step not the entire process.  If you want the approval to skip the remaining steps then set a flag on the record and bypass the remaining steps by checking on the entry criteria if that flag has been set..

Comment: So that checkbox is for when i have multiple apprivers in the same step? 

ok, gonna try that. Weird thing is, they told me in production environment those same rules, setup, and without such field, it does already that. 

But probably this issue never came up, because the record information used only matched one step at a time, as a coincidence

Comment: Correct the checkbox would bypass all the subsequent steps based on entry criteria.  And yes the existing approval process possibly bypassed the additional steps based on entry criteria ( but maybe not in all scenarios ).   

Just to be clear.  first response jumps out of current step.  unanimous requires all approvers to approve for that step before it proceeds to next step.

Comment: You understood correctly, thanks for the answer. And when now you say "additional approvers", you mean bellow "Automatically assign to approver(s).", where I can add a new one with "Add Row Remove Row"? Not a new approver in a new step?